# How to stop all YouTube videos when changing option in select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, youtube-api

I have several YouTube players in hidden div's that show / hide based on selection in a WP template. The issue I am running into is that if you are playing a video, then change the channel by using the select list the video keeps playing after it is hidden. You still hear audio from the original video while the new content loads. I get an error with the global var 'players' -> 'players.pauseVideo is not a function'. In the code I create an array of video players and tried to create a global stop function, whatever var I use, players, players_list etc I get the same error.

```
var players = new Array();
var players_list = ["ytpl-player1", "ytpl-player2", "ytpl-player3"];

function stopGlobal() {
    players_list.pauseVideo();
}
```

Comment: Type of `Array` has not method `pauseVideo` unless you prototyped one. You should call pause on video that you want to pause.

Comment: How would you do that in an efficient manner? If vid 1 is playing & select change - pause vid1? Im going to have 12 different players to show / hide. I appreciate the knowledge and any help! Thank you.

Comment: I guess that only one video will be playing at time. Then you are probably able to store reference to currently playing yt video. Or as pause() will be probably Promise based even via yt wrapper, you can iterate through that array and call pause() to each one..

Comment: I assign the class for the playing video -> var nowPlaying = "ytpl-playing"; and when I add nowPlaying.stopVideo(); on the change function I still get the error "nowPlaying.stopVideo is not a function"

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes. Just look at one of them.

```js
var players = new Array();
var players_list = ["ytpl-player1", "ytpl-player2", "ytpl-player3"];

for (item in players_list) {
    console.log('Trying to set "'+ players_list[item] + '" as index of array.');
    players[players_list[item]] = 'whatever';
}

console.log('Result:');
console.log(players);
```

Fix:

```js
var players = {
  "ytpl-player1": null,
  "ytpl-player2": null,
  "ytpl-player3": null,
};

Object.keys(players).forEach(function(key) {
  players[key] = 'new YT.Player(key, ...';
});

console.log('Result:');
console.log(players);
```

Then you can iterate again like above and call pauseVideo() on each value.

Comment: That outputs this in console Trying to set "ytpl-player1" as index of array.
(index):418 Trying to set "ytpl-player2" as index of array.
(index):418 Trying to set "ytpl-player3" as index of array.
(index):422 Result:
(index):423

Comment: Yup. That describes what you actually do.

Comment: Im struggling to grasp this, just one of those days. so if 'ytpl-player1' is selected, and you change, you should access it by 'ytpl-player1.stopVideo();'?

Comment: You can not use string as index of array. At this moment, you have empty array. Thats what I want to say.

Comment: I'll apologize up front, sorry man. How do I get it in an array so I can access it? I tried "$('#ytpl-player1').get(0).stopVideo();" and get "(index):534 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).get(...).stopVideo is not a function" which I assume is expected

Comment: Awesome, I moved the line "var players_list = ["ytpl-player1", "ytpl-player2", "ytpl-player3"];" under the var players and get this output in console "var players_list = ["ytpl-player1", "ytpl-player2", "ytpl-player3"];" Now I should be able to use $('#ytpl-player1").stopVideo()?

Comment: Still get "(index):537 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).get(...).stopVideo is not a function"